# Update PHP to use latest Curl Version

Tags: curl

We have installed Curl 7.46.0 but PHP is still referencing 7.35.0

How do we get PHP to use the latest installed version

curl--version shows correct version running but php working with previous version

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/665802

you need to update libcurl as well, since PHP uses that instead of CURL

Edit:
you can update libcurl by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

and restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and PHP-FPM if needed

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: thanks @MarkKirby, I'll keep that in mind for next time and will edit my answer a little bit

Comment: Leave me a comment @markkirby when you edit it, I will vote you up for making the effort.

Comment: @MarkKirby I hope this helps a little more than before